# Develop an ios applicaiton for TV remote controll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to develop an iPhone application which should work like a TV remote like i can change the TV Channel, increase-decrease volume level, phone and TV both should connected to the WIFI.

I have R&D on this but not found any efficient result. i don't know where to start on this.

Is any one worked on this type of application so please help me how to start on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on your TV connected to your device, and what API it offers.

Comment: You need control a peripheral by MFI. And then peripheral communicates with TV.

Comment: Or Bluetooth, communicate with TV directly.